# Flex chart ItemRollOver behavior

Tags: apache-flex, charts

I'm trying to prevent a default chart item roll over highlight in a Spark column chart.

If you look at any of the chart examples on [this page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7bfd.html) , when you roll over any of the chart series items, they turn a darkened shade of their original colour. This is what I want to prevent.

So far I have had no luck with using the itemRollOverColor property, as this only allows you to set it to one specific colour for the whole chart (my app has several different coloured series on the chart at once). Also, trying to leverage the itemRollOver event (with preventDefault() etc) hasn't worked either.

Does anyone have any idea what I am missing here?

Thanks for reading guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove chart's selectionMode property or set it to "none".

If you realy need multiple ChartItem selection you'll have to override default item renderer by creating a class that implements IDataRenderer interface and setting  itemRenderer style to your class for the chart series

Comment: Thanks David, I think I will have to override the item renderer.

Comment: In case anyone has this problem: I got this working using the approach David mentions above (creating an ItemRenderer for the chart series items). [this article](http://tuckwat.com/blog/flex/flex-custom-column-chart-itemrenderer/) was particularly helpful.